# Multiple fixed backgrounds without background-attachment: fixed

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm creating a simple website that is supposed to have a parallax-type effect. Originally it was using `background-attachment: fixed;`, however that's causing a repaint on each scroll, leading to some noticeable FPS drops.

Here is the desired effect, which in the real use-case, is causing slight stuttering:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container,
#container2 {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}

#container {
    background-image: url('http://fillmurray.com/1200/1200');
}

#container2 {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1200/1200')
}

#more-content {
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: 35vh 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="more-content">
    Here's some more content
</div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

As a work-around, I've created a div and applied a `::before` pseudo-element that's `position: fixed;`, and I've set it into the background by doing `z-index: -1;`. I've added `will-change: transform;` to avoid repaint issues.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#container::before {
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
    will-change: transform;
}

#more-content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: 50vh 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="more-content">
    Here's some more content
</div>
```

The problem is introduced once I try and create a *second* fixed image, beneath the section that says "Here's some more content". Because `position: fixed;` takes the element out of the flow (despite its parent being `position: relative`), I can't figure out a method to incorporate the second image, preserving the "wipe" effect in my first example. Being that they occupy the same space, only *one* image shows.

I've seen a few people ask similar questions, though most were not recent, nor did they have any answers.

I'm open to suggestions, otherwise I'll be tasking myself with a JavaScript workaround.